# How to use mxnet RNN symbol to generate lstm

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

I've found RNN symbol is added in mxnet v0.7 python lib.
Now, I'm trying to use it to impl lstm in example/rnn with python.
But I have no idea because there's no document or any information of the input and output.
Can anyone give me any advice?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they have already given a simple example on how to use RNN symbol to build LSTM (they have mode option for this, i.e., mode='lstm'). Here is the example, check it out: https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/example/rnn/rnn_cell_demo.py